# Python Decoding/Encoding Problems

Tags: python, http, character-encoding

I know that a lot of people on the Internet have expressed having problems with string encodings in Python but no matter what I try, I can't figure out how to fix my problem. Essentially, I'm using TCP sockets to connect to a Web Server and then I send that Server a HTTP Request. I read the response into a series of buffers that I decode and concatenate to create a complete response as a string. When I get the response however, I'm getting **UnicodeDecodingErrors**. I want to use my program to go on to many different websites so is there any solution to this problem that would work with just about any site I give it?

Thank you for your time.

Some code:

```
def getAllFromSocket(socket):
    '''Reads all data from a socket and returns a string of it.'''
    more_bytes = True
    message = ''
    if(socket!=None):
        while(more_bytes):
        buffer = socket.recv(1024)
        if len(buffer) == 0:
            more_bytes = False
        else:
            message += buffer.decode('utf-8')
    return message
```

So when I do this:

```
received_message = getAllFromSocket(my_sock)
```

I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 1023: unexpected end of data
```

Comment: Can you give some sample code/data that illustrates your problem?

Comment: search for pycon 2012 unicode on youtube. There's an awesome video on unicode in python2/3

Comment: You most probably need to parse the `Content-Type` header and decode appropriately. There is no "magic" solution (except for using a library instead of rolling your own code for a problem that has been solved one hundred thousand times).

Comment: Yeah, the data you're receiving isn't `utf-8`. Determine the actual type and decode it from that.

Comment: Ok so I use the http header field to find the content charset. Will the http header also be in this charset or will the http header always be utf-8?

Comment: @Hudson: The header will be ASCII (no characters with codepoints > 0x7f)). Can't you just use urllib for the request? It's part of the Python stdlib.

Comment: @NiklasB. I could but I was trying to learn about the protocols themselves

Comment: @Hudson: That's a very valid argument :) In that case you want to learn a bit about character encodings first, though. Anyways, the procedure is to (a) read the headers (terminated by `\r\n\r\n`) (b) interpret the headers as plain ASCII and extract the `Content-Type`, `Content-Encoding` and `Content-Size` (c) read the number of bytes specified by `Content-Size` and decode them according to the other headers. That should allow you to parse most single-document responses.

Comment: found the video I was referring to: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc&feature=relmfu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try finding the encoding of the data using [UnicodeDammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit). Make sure you're getting `utf-8`. You can also choose to ignore errors:

```
buffer.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

Comment: The data doesn't seem to be UTF-8, so this is a bad workaround at best.